# Add text to 'Ready Page' in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I added few custom pages to my Installer. These pages gather some data from user and disk, and I'd like to show this data to user before final installation step starts. Inno Setup has 'Ready to Install' page exactly for this purpose.

How can I add text to this page? By default it shows to me:

```
Destination location:
  C:\Program Files\MyProgram
```

I'd like to append some text here. Is it possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found it ... https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents:

> `function UpdateReadyMemo(Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo, MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;`
>
> If Setup finds the `UpdateReadyMemo` event function in the Pascal script, it is called automatically when the **Ready to Install** wizard page becomes the active page. It should return the text to be displayed in the settings memo on the **Ready to Install** wizard page as a single string with lines separated by the `NewLine` parameter. Parameter `Space` contains a string with spaces. Setup uses this string to indent settings. The other parameters contain the (possibly empty) strings that Setup would have used as the setting sections. The `MemoDirInfo` parameter for example contains the string for the **Selected Directory** section.

Comment: For an example of a use, see https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/main/Examples/CodeDlg.iss – or [Ready to Install wizard page looks empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53611072/850848) or [Inno Setup - Show custom components on Ready to Install page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63029465/850848).

Answer (score 13):

Alter the following code:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpReady then
  begin
    Wizardform.ReadyMemo.Lines.Add(''); { Empty string }
    Wizardform.ReadyMemo.Lines.Add('Setup HP-UX test created by Armand');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Inno already provides this hook in the `UpdateReadyMemo` event function.

Comment: This is much nicer than using `UpdateReadyMemo` You have to rebuild the entire string with the hook while here you just tack on what you need to say.

Comment: Very elegant solution. Much simpler than updating the memo. Has the small drawback that unless you do some serious trickery, you can only add lines at the bottom though. Also, it scrolls the box down to the end I think.

Comment: This works only if the `ReadyMemo` memo contained any default contents. Had it not, it won't show.

Answer (score 7):

You can hook into the setup process of the `ReadyMemo` `WizardPage` using this function:

> `function UpdateReadyMemo(Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo, MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;`
>
> If Setup finds the `UpdateReadyMemo` event function in the Pascal script, it is called automatically when the **Ready to Install** wizard page becomes the active page. It should return the text to be displayed in the settings memo on the **Ready to Install** wizard page as a single string with lines separated by the `NewLine` parameter. Parameter `Space` contains a string with spaces. Setup uses this string to indent settings. The other parameters contain the (possibly empty) strings that Setup would have used as the setting sections. The `MemoDirInfo` parameter for example contains the string for the **Selected Directory** section.

Official docs at: http://www.innosetup.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm

Here is a simple example implementation that adds a single line to the default content of the `ReadyMemo`:

```pascal
function UpdateReadyMemo(Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo, MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
begin
    Result := ''

    if MemoUserInfoInfo <> '' then begin
        Result := MemoUserInfoInfo + Newline + NewLine;
    end;
    if MemoDirInfo <> '' then begin
        Result := Result + MemoDirInfo + Newline + NewLine;
    end;
    if MemoTypeInfo <> '' then begin
        Result := Result + MemoTypeInfo + Newline + NewLine;
    end;
    if MemoComponentsInfo <> '' then begin
        Result := Result + MemoComponentsInfo + Newline + NewLine;
    end;
    if MemoGroupInfo <> '' then begin
        Result := Result + MemoGroupInfo + Newline + NewLine;
    end;
    if MemoTasksInfo <> '' then begin
        Result := Result + MemoTasksInfo + Newline + NewLine;
    end;

    Result := Result + 'My custom string';
end;
```

For your information: I tried adding this code to the accepted answer, but it got declined and I was told to write a comment or a new answer.

Answer (score 5):

Also, if you just want to change the pre-existing messages to something less generic, you can change them in your [Messages] section:

i.e.

```
[Messages]
ReadyMemoDir=Server location:
```

The default messages are:

- WizardReady
- ReadyLabel1
- ReadyLabel2a
- ReadyLabel2b
- ReadyMemoUserInfo
- ReadyMemoDir
- ReadyMemoType
- ReadyMemoComponents
- ReadyMemoGroup
- ReadyMemoTasks

Answer (score 2):

As the existing answers show already, implement [`UpdateReadyMemo` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=UpdateReadyMemo).

Implementing the function requires reimplementing an assembly of the default memo contents. Below is a less repetitive way to implement that.

```pascal
procedure AddToReadyMemo(var Memo: string; Info, NewLine: string);
begin
  if Info <> '' then Memo := Memo + Info + Newline + NewLine;
end;

function UpdateReadyMemo(
  Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo, MemoComponentsInfo,
  MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
begin
  AddToReadyMemo(Result, MemoUserInfoInfo, NewLine);
  AddToReadyMemo(Result, MemoDirInfo, NewLine);
  AddToReadyMemo(Result, MemoTypeInfo, NewLine);
  AddToReadyMemo(Result, MemoComponentsInfo, NewLine);
  AddToReadyMemo(Result, MemoGroupInfo, NewLine);
  AddToReadyMemo(Result, MemoTasksInfo, NewLine);

  Result := Result + 'Additional custom information';
end;
```

[image]